# JasperReports: generation error from java with external fonts

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

My program generates an  error for arabic letter :

```
cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStaticText to field 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
```

I am using:

- iReport 4.0.2
- Windows XP
- jasperreports-fonts-4.0.2.jar
- jasperreports 4.0.2.jar
- jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3

My .jrxml file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="strTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="vchDhirams" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="221" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement markup="none"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$P{strTitle}]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="37" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="294" y="17" width="135" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ستلام قسيمة]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Where is my fault? Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your code? Your report generates normally in iReport.

Comment: You should use textField for displaying parameter (or variable or field)